# How to include nested navigation graph using Kotlin with Android Navigation Component

Tags: android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

How can I create a navigation graph which includes another nested graph using Kotlin instead of XML?

This is the graph in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mainNavigationStart"
    app:startDestination="@id/auth_navigation">

    <include app:graph="@navigation/auth_navigation" />

</navigation>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is creating the same graph using Kotlin. I've started with

```
controller.createGraph(startDestination = R.id.auth_navigation) {
     // include R.id.auth_navigation
}
```

however inside the builder lambda there is no method such as `include` available.

Answer (score 0):

I would include destinations from nested graph to another graph like this:

```java
        navController.graph.addAll(nestedGraph)
```

Comment: I may solve my problem however I need to include graph defined in XML, which means I have its `Int` identifier (`R.navigation.auth_navigation`) while `addAll` accepts object of type `NavGraph`. How can I get this object from id such as `R.navigation.auth_navigation`?

Comment: You can inflate an xml with something like that
`val nestedGraph = navController.navInflater.inflate(R.id.nested_graph)`
and then you can add it with the aforementioned code